# Update sql fixture with other sql

Tags: sql, database, fixture

For a list of automated tests we use sql fixtures to prepare the database in a desired state. The problem is however that the database is frequently updated where columns can be added, or removed from different tables. This is done with other sql files. It is possible that the changed tables are mentioned in the sql fixtures.

Is there some way to update the existing sql fixtures with the sql database updates. It is possible that multiple fixtures have overlap in tables so each fixture should be updated independently.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I'd try to get a handle on the migration process if things are truly going too fast. Schemas do change but if you're spending a significant amount of time just keeping up with that, it's worth taking a step back to try to stabilize things.

The next thing to do is to minimize the impact of schema changes: if you have a series of monolithic fixtures which set up entire data-states in one go, break them apart and use a compositional approach. For example, if you have a `users` table, there should be only one fixture that inserts new users. Other fixtures which depend on user data should rely on the user-fixture to take care of that before inserting what they need. Keep the single responsibility principle in mind and compose the data-state for a given test by invoking a chain of discrete, well-defined fixtures. This way, if a column is added to or removed from `users`, you only have to change a single fixture.

Finally, if you *really* want to automate things, you're getting into generating code. There's one major caveat here which is that it's very difficult to generate test data humans can easily work with while debugging. If you're fine with meaningless gibberish in all your text fields, then it's not a dealbreaker, but it is something to be aware of.

Relational databases expose the structure and metadata in the information schema so you can query it exactly like you do your own tables. You'll need to consult the documentation for your specific database vendor since there are differences among them, but you can for example list the tables in your database with the query `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables`. Likewise for `information_schema.columns`; other tables describe primary and foreign keys and constraints; and so forth. Use that information to build queries which insert well-formed data, and you're off to the races. This is *almost certainly* more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I have investigated your approach on our situation. The problem lies in two parts. The main part of the application runs on a legacy database handler that has no migration capabilities. It even has it's own form of relation structure implemented that doesn't work with the native variant. For this reason we cannot use the migrations as suggested. The second problem is that we do not only have semi-static data like a user table, but also data that has to be processed in multiple stages and we broke those into seperate test cases. For each of the cases we need a seperate fixture.